# Integrating with a bluetooth device using the Hands-Free Profile (HFP) on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, external-accessory

I have tried to connect bluetooth Hands-Free Profile (HFP) to iPhone device using `External Accessory` and download this sample app
[Using sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html)
but bluetooth Headset device list not show on screen.

Also using CBCentralManager [CoreBluetooth.framework] but bluetooth Headset device list not show on screen.
 other iPhone is connected and show connected mac, iPhone on list.

My problem is how to connect bluetooth Hands-Free Profile (HFP) to iPhone?

Comment: `CoreBluetooth.framework`: Only for BLE devices, so if you device is not BLE, it won't be listed there. Some devices with specific profiles won't be seen with ExternalAccessory (like keyboard, etc.). So my guess it's the case if your device only has HFP.

Comment: @Larme i am using BLE Headset.

Comment: You need to be using MFI framework, not Corebluetooth.